# VS Code on Mac.... "The Program 'xxxxxxxxx' has exited with code 0 (0x0)" ... expecting step over to work but debuggin exits on click

Tags: c#, debugging

Here's what I get when I click on Step Over

[image]

Here's what it is before clicking on Step Over

[image]

What I am expecting is for the debugger to step over onto line 10, but it just keeps exiting the debug mode, as can be seen on the last line of the debug console.

I have tried the following:

1. Restarting Visual Code
2. Deleting and reinstating the .vscode folder conatining launch.json and tasks.json
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code
4. Building new console and debug files and starting from a fresh
5. Removing settings.json file
6. Moving VS Code to application folder (and then reinstalling again)
7. Checked same code files with someone else's VS Code and their debugging mode allows step over and works as expected.

Is there any potential fixes I am missing or any thing that can be spotted as wrong on the screenshots? Appreciate any help.

I'm running this Mac OS Big Sur v11.1 if that's relevant.

Comment: Try deleting your bin and obj directories. Is the output writing hello world 5 times by the way? Maybe you clicked continue instead of step over?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However tried deleting and debugging just now and still no joy. Yes it prints correctly. I have tried all the buttons each one ends up giving the same exit code message. I have also tried this with identical code that debugger is working on with my colleagues macbook air. So it isn't an issue with the coide itself. I have tried around 12 different programs now and all fail to be debugged correctly.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?